# Efficiently removing overlapping regions from a segmentation image using rectangle coordinates in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, multidimensional-array, image-segmentation

I'm working on a project where I have a segmentation image represented in a world frame, along with the coordinates of rectangles defined by their centers and corners within the same world frame. I need to develop a solution in C++ to efficiently remove the portions of the segmentation image that overlap with these rectangles.

Could someone provide insights or algorithms on how to achieve this task specifically in C++?

The below images show the original segmentation image and the portion of the segmentation image which I am trying to mask off. In the second image, the green lines represent the union of the rectangles at arbitrary angles in the world frame. The red shaded region are the pixels I want to remove.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. Create a white mask with full image size. 2.draw your rectangles (or the union polygon) filled black 3. img.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0), mask).

Comment: @Micka My questions for the steps:
1. What is the full image size here? It includes the segmentation image in the world frame and a "padding" on all 4 side of this image which is much larger and can contain all the rectangles right? How do I create this white mask with full image size?

2.  Does it make a difference if I draw each rectangle separately or if I draw the union polygon in black? What opencv function can I use to draw the rectangles at arbitrary angles given their corners in the world frame?

3. What is img here? Is it the segmentation image?

Comment: since you keep talking about frames, which is not apparent from the picture itself, you should present a [mre], i.e. some code and data (data, not illustration), so we can have something to work with. -- is that an illustration or data? how was it made, aside from the hand-drawn scribbles? on the basis of what data? -- from your descriptions, I doubt this is computer vision. it sounds more like computer graphics, geometry. maybe SLAM but you didn't say that.

Comment: @hunterlineage if I understood correctly, you want to mask out the segmentation image (make the red marked regions black?). Create a white image with the size of your segmentation image and go for the other steps. Yes, it makes a difference to draw the single rectangles or the union polygon. Which one is more efficient depends on how many overlapping rectangles there are and how expensive your union-computation is (and whether it is done anyways). You can use opencv's drawContours function or cv::fillConvexPoly (if polygons are convex) with value -1 for thickness (filled).